# Changing the addNewRow icon placement in material-table for React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I put the onRowAdd handler in the editable option of material-table component to get the ability to add a new row. Everything works well, but I don't know how to change the default placement of RowAdd button (normally, just after the search field). In my example, I'd like to see this button inside the row, provided for filtering fields (the row added by options.filtering.true). Is it possible? How do I change the default placement of this button? The source code of my component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import MaterialTable from 'material-table';

export default function MyTable2() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    columns: [
      { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
      { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
      { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
      {
        title: 'Birth Place',
        field: 'birthCity',
        lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
      },
    ],
    data: [
      { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63 },
      {
        name: 'Zerya Betül',
        surname: 'Baran',
        birthYear: 2017,
        birthCity: 34,
      },
    ],
  });

  return (
    <MaterialTable
      title="Editable Example"
      columns={state.columns}
      data={state.data}
      options={{
        filtering:true
      }}
      editable={{
        onRowAdd: (newData) =>
          new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              resolve();
              setState((prevState) => {
                const data = [...prevState.data];
                data.push(newData);
                return { ...prevState, data };
              });
            }, 600);
          }),
        onRowUpdate: (newData, oldData) =>
          new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              resolve();
              if (oldData) {
                setState((prevState) => {
                  const data = [...prevState.data];
                  data[data.indexOf(oldData)] = newData;
                  return { ...prevState, data };
                });
              }
            }, 600);
          })
      }}
    />
  );
}
```